# How accurate are the most accurate calculations?

Tags: molecular-modeling, periodic-system, full-configuration-interaction, atomic-physics, high-precision

Taking into account the fact that the theory of quantum gravity does not exist and the QED calculations are not possible for most realistic chemical systems, what levels of accuracy can we expect from a theoretical calculation on simple (small) materials? Examples that come to mind are:

1. Simplest molecular materials: $^3\ce{He}$, $^4\ce{He}$, $\ce{H_2}$.
2. Simplest periodic systems, i.e. metallic $\ce{Li}$.

Comment: I gave an answer, and then saw a close vote. Maybe it was because you used  "etc.", which makes it "open ended".  You have given 3 specific atomic/molecular systems, but for periodic systems there is no end. Specific examples would help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question accordingly. There is still no answer for the periodic system though...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Exhibit 1: Ground state hyperfine splitting of the H atom:

```
1420405751767(1) mHz (present most accurate experiment)
142045199        mHz (present most accurate theory)
```

The error in the theory is due to the difficulty in treating the nuclear structure (2 up quarks + 1 down).

### Exhibit 2: Ground state hyperfine splitting of the muonium atom:

```
4463302780(050) Hz (present most accurate experiment)
4463302880(550) Hz (present most accurate theory)
```

Why does it agree so well? μ$^+$ is a fundamental particle and therefore has no nuclear structure. QED is the correct theory for describing the interaction between pure electric charges (e$^-$ and μ$^+$). The only QFD (quantum flavordynamics) needed is for the electro-weak interaction *between* the particles (not for interactions within sub-nuclear particles), and QFD calculations were done [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03841) in anticipation of more accurate experiments to come.

### Exhibit 3: Ground state hyperfine splitting of the He atom:

```
6739701177(0016) Hz (present most accurate experiment)
6739699930(1700) Hz (present most accurate theory)
```

Notice how much harder it is when you add an electron.

### Exhibit 5: $S\rightarrow P$ transition in the Li atom:

```
14903.632061014(5003) cm^-1 (present most accurate experiment)
14903.631765(0006670) cm^-1 (present most accurate theory)
```

### Exhibit 6: Ionization energy of the Li atom:

```
43487.15940(18) cm^-1 (present most accurate experiment)
43487.1590(080) cm^-1 (present most accurate theory)
```

### Exhibit 7: Ionization energy of the Be atom:

```
76192.64(0060) cm^-1 (present most accurate experiment)
76192.699(007) cm^-1 (present most accurate theory)
```

**Notice that theory is 1 order of magnitude *more accurate* than experiment!!!**

### Exhibit 8: Atomization energy of the H$_2$ molecule:

```
35999.582834(11) cm^-1 (present most accurate experiment)
35999.582820(26) cm^-1 (present most accurate theory)
```

See [here for more info](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09471.pdf).

### Exhibit 9: Fundamental vibration of the H$_2$ molecule:

```
4161.16632(18) cm^-1 (present most accurate experiment)
4161.16612(90) cm^-1 (present most accurate theory)
```

See [here for HD and D$_2$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6390.pdf).

Comment: In "Ideas of Quantum Chemistry" by Lucjan Piela there is a table with the contributions of various physical effects (non-relativistic, Breit, QED, beyond QED) to the ionization energy and dipole polarizability of the He atom, compared with experiment. IP(th):5945204223(42) MHz, IP(exp): 5945204238(45) MHz. $\alpha$(th):1383760.79(23) a.u.$\times10^{-6}$, $\alpha$(exp):1383791(67) a.u.$\times10^{-6}$

Comment: Only 10 digits? Table II in my paper gives it to 11 digits: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Carbon/blob/master/C.pdf

Comment: well, maybe the reference of the book is a bit old, from 2001 and 2004.

Comment: @NikeDattani: "Notice that theory is 1 order of magnitude more accurate than experiment!!!" I don't get this. First, they seem off in the hundredths (maybe a typo). But also, how do you know it's 1 order of magnitude more accurate if you don't have the experimental reference? Do you mean more precise?

Comment: @AndrewRosen There's no typo. The difference is 4.1 in the hundredths digits, which is smaller than the uncertainty for the most accurate experiment. In this case theory is more precise, and more accurate too.

Comment: I am curious how the theory can be more precise and more accurate than the experiment.  How do we know that to be true?  Precision I can believe, accuracy should be based on experiments should it not?

Comment: @TristanMaxson That's a question for philosophy and opinion about semantics. There's some elements for which you *cannot* do experiments at all, but the theoretical calculation will be just as accurate as it would be for other systems with the same number of electrons. Unless you believe for example that the Schrödinger equation should be the same for 100 of the elements, and wrong for the other 18. The ionization energy of the hydrogen atom is known better by theory than by experiment. It's only 1e- so easy to calculate, but not an easy element for ionization experiments.

Comment: @NikeDattani Interesting approach to thinking about it.  I think I am willing to believe that then based on that argument.

Comment: @TristanMaxson If there's an element on which you cannot do experiments at all (or you can experimentally only get very poor information because the element has a half-life of less than a second), then surely the theoretical calculation can be more precise ***and more accurate***. In the above example, Be is poisonous so experimental information about it is rare, but it has only 4e- so calculations can be done very well. To say it's not accurate would be to say that quantum electrodynamics is not accurate, since all numerics are converged. But QED is accurate to far more digits than seen here.

Comment: This is quite interesting! It would be great if references for all of them could be added to read more on them.

Comment: @RashidRafeek I can add them but it will take a long time, if you look at my 2020 paper on the carbon atom, which is free on arXiv, the references should be there!

Comment: Oh okay thanks. That's fine. I'll look into that paper.